# SVN AND TFS structure for Cordova/Phonegap app with REST/Web API service

Tags: c#, ios, svn, cordova, tfs

I'm trying to get our SVN and TFS repo structures finalized for a new mobile project we are starting. The code is in 2 (or 3) sections:

1. REST/Web API/service for all database interaction
2. The "web" code, which consists of css, html, js (and Angular) etc
3. iOS project...Phonegap/Cordova code

I've already created a project on our Jenkins (iOS) build server and have that configured to build the iOS source code, create an IPA file, and upload to TestFlight for the testers. I also have created a TFS repository for the REST/Web api code that is building successfully, I'm just waiting for my permissions to deploy this code.

So, as you can see, lots (not really) of moving parts to this application. The problem that I have now, is that there is code that is technically "shared" between the iOS code and the Web (service) code, which is all of #2.

I've read about svn:externals, but obviously that is for code that is encompassed COMPETELY in SVN (I think). How can I accomplish #2 to work with both source control systems?

Edit: I am restricted to using SVN and/or TFS for source code repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Visual Studio Tools for Git (2012 or 2013) and switch all development to git? This also allows you to setup TFS 2013 (or Visual Studio Online) as your git server should you want to. Or use [svnBridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/) for TFS and see if you can get that to work with the `svn:externals` (never tried that angle before).

You could also use `git svn`and `git tf` in combination with local git submodules in a local git repository (but store the remote masters in tfs and svn respectively), but that's making things more complex than need be.

And you can also use a build system to generate a NuGet package and reference that from Visual Studio/TFS, that way you'd have a single source for the package (hence easy reuse) and each application can be built in its own ecosystem.

And you can always install [AhnkSvn](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) or [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) and store all the Visual Studio stuff in Subversion too.

Comment: Sorry, I should have prefaced my question with "I am restricted to SVN and/or TFS for all source code repository". I'll look at the svnBridge stuff...

Comment: Would the Jenkins (iOS) project be able to grab from NuGet though? I thought that was only a VS thing.

Comment: You could have Jenkins create and publish the NuGet package. That way the source is controlled on the iOS side of your project. Have the iOS side reference the files directly. Creating a NuGet package and publishing it can be done from the commandline.

Comment: How would I go about creating a NuGet package when there's no csproj file (and coming from an iOS build machine)?

Comment: A NuGet is just a zip with an XML manifest. The NuGet executable can even be built using Mono. It wouldn't be standard,  but certainly possible.